# Add a checkbox to a dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which I add cells to dynamically. I want to add a checkbox as one of the cell elements. Specifically to element cell_0 of row0.
I tried `cell_0.innerHTML = <input type = "checkbox />;`but that didn't work.

```
var row0 = document.getElementById("jobsTable").insertRow(0);
var cell_0 = row0.insertCell(0);
cell_0.innerHTML = <input type="checkbox"/> ;
var cell_1 = row0.insertCell(1);
cell_1.innerHTML = "CIT Suite";
var cell_2 = row0.insertCell(2);
cell_2.innerHTML = "Buildroot";

<table id="jobsTable" class="container" align="center" style="width:40%">
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check your browser console for error messages—in your case I am very positive that line number 3 is going to give you issue. The innerHTML string needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @Terry That's correct. I missed the single quotes. It's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the html. `cell_0.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"/>';`

Comment: Thanks! That was silly of me!